# Compile ffmpeg for GPL use on Yocto

Tags: ffmpeg, yocto

From what I understood [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14802/can-i-use-ffmpeg-in-a-commercial-product), if I compile with the flag `--enable-gpl`, ffmpeg can be added in a commercial product.
In the recipe, there is: `PACKAGECONFIG[gpl] = "--enable-gpl,--disable-gpl"`

Thus, I created a `ffmpeg_%.bbappend` containing:

```
PACKAGECONFIG_append ="gpl"
```

But it seems I still have to put a value in `LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST`, most likely `commercial`. Is it a mistake from me or is it not handled properly by the main recipe?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not a mistake.

The `PACKAGECONFIG[gpl] = "--enable-gpl,--disable-gpl"` just adds a way to enable/disable building GPL-licensed parts of `ffmpeg`. It has nothing to do with whether you can use the result in a commercial product.

By setting `LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST_append = " commercial_ffmpeg"`, you're telling the buildsystem that you're allowed to build and use `ffmpeg`. That can be due to you having acquired a commercial license (or licenses), that you'r in a jurisdiction where you don't need commercial license(s), etc...

Note that in this case, these two `PACKAGECONFIG[gpl]` and `LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST` are orthogonal, they have nothing with each other to do.

The `LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST` is there to protect you, from adding things that might require commercial licenses by mistake / unknowingly.

Comment: Some additional FFmpeg specific info: if `--enable-gpl` is used then GPLv2.0+ applies to all of FFmpeg. FFmpeg has no commercial license (it is LGPLv2.1+ or GPLv2.0+ or "non-free/non-redistributable" depending on the configure options). FFmpeg doesn't care if it is used commercially: it only requires proper license compliance.

Comment: Well, it's not that FFmpeg has any commercial license; it's rather a question on whether FFmpeg implements something that requires a commercial license (eg a related example: MPEG4 contains patented technologies [1]m that might require a license, depending on your jurisdiction).

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4#Licensing